# Schwarz's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, inequality

If the functions $f$ and $g$ are in $L^2$ then whether the inequality (which is like the Schwartz's inequality) is correct or not? And if it is correct then how it is proved?

$$\left(\int f g dx\right)^2 \leq \int f g^2 dx \int f dx$$

Comment: I think you have to assume $f \ge 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this form, the inequality is incorrect. For example, consider $f(x) = g(x) = x$ on $(-1, 1)$.

However, if you replace $f$ with $|f|$ on the right-hand side, the inequality becomes correct. To see this, use the decomposition $fg = (\sqrt{|f|}g) \cdot (\operatorname{sgn}(f) \sqrt{|f|})$ and apply the standard Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thank you very much Dominik. I m reading Titchmarsh's "The theory of function's", the Chapter for Dirichlet Series and many times I havent got any clue of what he is doing. Do you mind checking my last question and see if you could help? Is on the mean value half plane of a D.S

Comment: I don't think I know how to solve your other question. At the moment, it is put on hold anyways, as it is a question with poor quality. To improve the question, you should first state all the assumptions on the functions, write what you want to prove in $\LaTeX$ and tell us what you have tried so far. Then the question might be reopened and someone could answer it.

Comment: With $f\geq 0,$ the value $\int fg^2$ may be $\infty.$ Of course that makes the inequality valid, but a proof should not assume that $\int fg^2 <\infty.$ (Example: $f(x)=g(x)=1/x^{1/3}$  in $L^2[0,1]$.) ...+1 anyway. it's a minor flaw.